# ExpressJS IP and AngularJS $http get

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to learn ExpressJS and I'm having trouble getting IP address from an Express route to display in the browser via Angular controller.

I'm using 2 Nodejs modules (request-ip and geoip2) to get the IP and then lookup geolocation data for that IP. Then trying to use Angular to display the geolocation data in the browser using an Angular $http get call.

My Express route for the IP:

```
// get IP address
router.get('/ip', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('requestIP is ' + ip);
    // geolocation
    geoip2.lookupSimple(ip, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        //return res.status(400).json({error: 'Something happened'});//default
        return res.sendStatus(400).json({error: 'Something happened'});
        }
        else if (result) {
        return res.send(result);
      }
    });
});
```

And my AngularJS controller code:

```
function MainController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = 'Hello World';
    vm.location = '';
    vm.getLocation = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'localhost:8000/ip'
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return vm.location = result;
        });
      }; 
    };
```

The Hello World message displays but not the location...? I can also go to localhost:8000/ip and see the `JSON result`. The `result` doesn't appear in Chrome's console either. The result is a json object like this:

```
{"country":"US","continent":"NA","postal":"98296","city":"Snohomish","location":{"accuracy_radius":20,"latitude":47.8519,"longitude":-122.0921,"metro_code":819,"time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles"},"subdivision":"WA"}
```

I'm not sure why the Hello Word displays and the location doesn't when it seems that I have everything configured correctly... so obviously I'm doing something wrong that I don't see...?

Comment: with your promise, use the catch block in order to catch any errors, after .then chain the call to that function to another call to catch and do a console.log or whatever, you might be getting an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have initialised 'vm.location' as a string when in fact it is a JSON object.

   `vm.location = {};`
2. You need to adjust the url paramater in your request to:

   `url: '/ip'`
3. As you are sending back JSON from Express.js, you should change your response line to:

   `return res.json(result);`

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question.

Comment: I can't comment unfortunately on the question as I do not have 50 rep, however that could have actually been the issue with the code and hence the answer

Comment: @user3125823 do you need the full 'localhost:8000' under url or does it instead require something like 'url: '/ip'?

Comment: @LJH unfortunately it wasn't. The {} displays in the browser tho, if you have other ideas... I'm all ears.

Comment: In your HTML, are you using angular data binding to make that appear, e.g. {{vm.location}}?

I would do something like:
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <div data-ng-init="vm.getLocation">
            {{vm.location}}
        </div>
     </div>

Comment: @user3125823 please try changing the url in the request to '/ip' as I commented earlier. Also, I missed the brackets in my data-ng-init comment from earlier, sorry, it should read ...="vm.getLocation()"

Comment: @LJH, thanks for your efforts, because you stuck with it, I chose your answer - as it helped me the most. All 3 answers helped but yours the most. thanks again - I got it working!

Comment: @user3125823 you're most welcome, glad it helped, I can finally comment now lol. You could edit your question to show what you did to fix things as I'm sure people would find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `vm.getLocation()` somewhere in your code after this?
The data you need is under `result.data` from the response object.
Also in order to display the data in the html you have to specify which property to display from the `vm.location` object (`vm.location.country`, `vm.location.city` etc..).

From angular docs about $http:

> The response object has these properties:
>   **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>   **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>   **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>   **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>   **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Comment: I can't just grab the whole result object to display all of it?

Comment: "The result doesn't appear in Chrome's console either." -- Use `.catch(function(error) { console.log(error) } )` to see what's the error.

Comment: of course you can, depends on what you aiming. Your code looks fine, it's probably something that you haven't shared with us.

Comment: ok cool. Just want to get this working first before I drill down on that. All the other code is boilerplate pretty much. I used the express generator for most of it.

Comment: thanks for your help, your answer helped me understand things a bit better. I chose the other answer simply because he kept pointing things out that helped me get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this express js and angular hosted on the same port? If so please replace your

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'localhost:8000/ip'
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return vm.location = result;
});
```

with

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/ip'
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return vm.location = result;
});
```

It may be considered as CORS call and you have it probably disabled.
You can also specify second function to `then` (look code below) and see if error callback is called.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/ip'
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return vm.location = result;
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help - good info, I chose the other answer, simply because he kept pointing things out to me that eventually helped me get it right.